# Use PHP variable to substitute Swiper autoplay time?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, swiper.js

I'm looking to allow users to pick the duration the slide autoplay speed is via the user-friendly Wordpress Customizer. I'm wondering how I would get that PHP variable (in ms) to modify the slider autoplay variable in JS. I'm new to AJAX and am just wondering how I'd go about using it to modify:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    paginationClickable: !0,
    centeredSlides: !0,
    autoplay: 3500, // I'M TRYING TO REPLACE THIS WITH A PHP VARIABLE
    speed: 1500,
    loop: !0,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: !1
});
```

Someone told me to try 
`autoplay: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'slider_duration', '3' ); ?>,`

but knew that wouldn't work and it obviously didn't.
Also the 'get_theme_mod' is the wordpress variable I'm calling to try to replace the autoplay value with.

Hopefully I can make this slider that much more customizable for the non-code-friendly clients I work with.

Comment: use `wp_localize_script` with your variable, then access from js to localized global `js` variable you defined

Comment: Samvel, thank you! That's exactly what I needed.